# Output current app's build version as a string - Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, versioning, info.plist

I want to output the app's current build version as a string onto my app's about view.

Is there a method of reading this dynamically from the info.plist file or elsewhere rather than hardcoding it in?

**E.g:** Build Version: 1.0

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use this code to pull it out of the plist:

```cs
NSBundle.MainBundle.InfoDictionary [new NSString ("CFBundleVersion")].ToString ();
```

You can also use `CFBundleShortVersionString`, which is the other value for versions. Xamarin recently added support for both in Xamarin Studio.

Comment: NSBundle.MainBundle.InfoDictionary is really useful to me for grabbing other strings that I need. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
public string AppVersion
{
    get
    {
         var appVersionString = NSBundle.MainBundle.ObjectForInfoDictionary("CFBundleShortVersionString").ToString();
         var appBuildNumber = NSBundle.MainBundle.ObjectForInfoDictionary("CFBundleVersion").ToString();

         return $"v{appVersionString} b{appBuildNumber}";
    }
}
```